# CATextLayer - how to disable implicit animations?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, core-animation, calayer

This drives me mad. Whenever I change value of `CATextLayer.foregroundColor` property the change is animated no matter what I do. For example I have `CATextLayer` called `layer` which is sublayer of `CALayer` `superlayer`:

```
layer.removeAllAnimations()
superlayer.removeAllAnimations()
superlayer.actions = ["sublayers" : NSNull()]
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0)
CATransaction.disableActions()
CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions)
layer.actions = ["foregroundColor" : NSNull()]
layer.actions = ["content" : NSNull()]
layer.foregroundColor = layoutTheme.textColor.CGColor
CATransaction.commit()
```

And it will still animates! Please help, how can I disable the implicit animations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `CATransaction.disableActions()` does not do what you think it does. You need to say `CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)`.

And then you can get rid of all the other stuff you're saying, as it is pointless. This code alone is sufficient to change the color without animation:

```
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
layer.foregroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor // or whatever
```

(You *can* wrap it in a `begin()`/`commit()` block if you have some other reason to do so, but there is no need just in order to switch off implicit layer property animation.)

Comment: Thank you sooo much. I cannot believe it was this. I tried everything else but I thought that `CATransaction.disableActions()` must do the some thing as `CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)`... My bad.

Comment: `CATransaction.disableActions()` fetches a Bool value reporting whether actions are in fact disabled - and you are then just throwing away the Bool (which you didn't care about anyway).